# Unwrapping element from parent if it is an only child - JSoup

Tags: jsoup

How would I go about unwrapping an element from its immediate parent if it is an only child. My version of JSoup is 1.6.3 and I cannot upgrade it.

I have tried using the :only-child selector but I don't think this is available in my version of JSoup.

e.g.

```
<p>
    <span>Some text</span>
</p>
```

should become...

```
<span>Some text</span>
```

But...

```
<div>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some more text</p>
</div>
```

should stay as it is.

Thanks, Michael.

**Update:**

Desired outcomes...

In the following situation I **do** want the span to be selected (i.e. where the child element is the only child of its parent):

```
<p><span>Text</span></p>
```

In the following situations I **do not** want the span to be selected (i.e. (1) where the child element is the only child node of its parent but the parent also contains content (2) where the parent element contains more than one child):

```
<p>Some text <span>continued</span></p>

<p><span>Text</span><a href="#">Link</a></p>
```

Once I have selected the correct child items I wish to unwrap them from their parent elements. This can be done using the unwrap() method. My main issue is selecting the child elements to unwrap in the first place.

Comment: I do not clearly understand your question. What stops you from just selecting the span itself? Provide some code of your work so far and I'll try to help out!

Comment: Because I want to select child elements which are the only child of their parent element. If the parent element contains content as well as the child element I do not want to select the child element. I will update my question to more clearly describe my desired outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code finds an `Element` which has only one child and no matter what `HTML` tags they are.

```
 Elements items = doc.select("body *");

    for (Element item : items) {

        if(item.parent() != null && item.parent().children().size() == 1 &&  StringUtil.isBlank(item.parent().ownText()))
        {
            System.out.println(item.parent().tagName() + " -> " + item.tagName() + " [" + item.ownText() + "]");
        }

    }
```